# How get value from function which is executed by Thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, return

I have main_script.py which import scripts which get data from webpages. I want do this by use multithreading. I came up with this solution, but it does not work:

main_script:

```
import script1
temp_path = ''
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=script1.Main,
                             name='Script1',
                             args=(temp_path, ))

thread1.start()
thread1.join()
```

script1:

```
class Main:
    def __init__()
    def some_func()
    def some_func2()

    def __main__():
        some_func()
        some_func2()
        return callback
```

Now only 1 way I know to get value of callback from script1 to main_script is:

main_script:

```
import script1
temp_path = ''
# make instance of class with temp_path
inst_script1 = script1.Main(temp_path)

print("instance1:")
print(inst_script1.callback)
```

It's works but then I run instances of scripts one-by-one, no concurrently.

Anybody has any idea how handle that? :)

Comment: The only way threads communicate with one another is through shared objects. One common way of sharing would be to have your main thread create some kind of a container object (e.g., a dictionary), and then pass a reference to the container as an arg to the thread's main function--same as how you pass the `temp_path`.  Then the thread function can stash its result in the dictionary where the main thread can later find it.

Comment: P.S., For a long-running thread that will _continually_ produce results, you might choose to use  a queue instead of a dictionary.

Comment: P.P.S., The simplest way, OK for quick hacks, but not so good for "serious" code, would be for the two threads to simply access the same global variable.  (e.g., `global result`, ... `result=whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

First off if you are using threading in Python make sure you read: https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock. Unless you are using C modules or a lot of I/O you won't see the scripts run concurrently. Generally speaking, `multiprocessing.pool` is a better approach.

If you are certain we want threads rather then processes you can use a mutable variable to store the result.  For example, a dictionary which keeps track of the result of each thread.

```
result = {}

def test(val, name, target):
   target[name] = val * 4 

temp_path = 'ASD'
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=test,
                             name='Script1',
                             args=(temp_path, 'A', result))

thread1.start()
thread1.join()
print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response. Yes, I readed about GIL, but it's doesn't make me any problem yet. Generally I solve my problem, because I find solution on other website. Code like this now:

Main_script:

```
import queue
import script1
import script2

queue_callbacks = queue.Queue()

threads_list = list()

temp_path1 = ''
thread1 = threading.Thread(target= lambda q, arg1: q.put(Script1.Main(arg1)),
                         name='Script1',
                         args=(queue_callbacks, temp_path1, ))
thread1.start()

temp_path2 = ''
thread2 = threading.Thread(target= lambda q, arg1: q.put(Script2.Main(arg1)),
                         name='Script2',
                         args=(queue_callbacks, temp_path2, ))
thread2.start()

for t in threads_list:
            t.join()

while not kolejka_callbacks.empty():
    result = queue_callbacks.get()
    callbacks.append({"service": result.service, "callback": result.callback, "error": result.error})
```

And this works fine. Now I have other problem, because I want this to work in big scale, where I have a hundreds of scripts and handle this by e.q. 5 threads. 
In general, is there any limit to the number of threads running at any one time?